# Access Jwt Authorization header from javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers, authorization, jwt

I have a client(phone app) that has a JWT token to access our backend servers. I'm creating a javascript single page application(SPA) that will be hosted in a WebView. I need to get that Auth token and pass it along in the calls the SPA makes to another server(connected via SignalR) which will use it to access the data and return it to the user.

My plan for this was to Pass the JWT Token in the Header when the WebView connects to the SPA. I then wanted the SPA to extract the Token and use it when it connects via SignalR to the backend.

However, I have found that it is very difficult to access the auth header from the SPA javascript itself.

I have found many articles that seem related but none that really explain this specific case clearly.

**Does anybody know of a way I can access and extract the JWT that was used when connecting to the site? Or, alternatively, a different approach I could take for acquiring and passing the JWT from the APP?**

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to save your token to cookie so even your signalR request can also have that token cookie. It sounds not a good idea to extract JWT at client since it requires private key as well.

Comment: When I said "extract" I simply meant get access to the JWT as a string from the header so I can pass it along to the SignalR connection. Not actually crack open the JWT.

Comment: ah ok, I misunderstood that. But save that to cookie will solve your needs right?

Comment: Perhaps, but it seems storing the JWT token in a cookie wouldn't be the safest route, want to limit where it gets exposed/saved.

Comment: Since I'm struggling to find a way to do this through the headers I might just expose an Init function in the Javascript that takes the JWT token. WebViews can call javascript functions so I think it'll work.